# Set initial extent programmatically Android

Tags: android, extents, arcgis-android

I need to dynamically set the extent when the map loads.  I have graphics that are being added to the map layer and want the extent to allow all the graphics to be shown.

Currently I am getting a min x and y value and max x and y value based off the points that are being used to add the graphics.

Then I try to use set extent with an envelope that contains the min and max values of x and y.

So am I missing something to set the bounds so that the map will show the correct portion of the map?

Comment: Any code to share?  Are you setting the extent in the ```OnStatusChangedListener```?  Some operations can only be set after ```MapView``` has been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely familiar with the android API, but in the JavaScript API, there's a function that allows you to take an array of graphics and extract the bounds of all returned features as if it were a single feature, then use a centerAndZoom() method to zoom the map to the graphic. Maybe the Android API has something similar?

Comment: It is important that you wait for ```GraphicLayer```s to be initialized before trying to get extents used to set bounds dynamically.  The Android API does not have a ```centerAndZoom()``` method. The API allows you to center but the developer manages the zoom.

Comment: It does. Just looked it up. Go to the android API reference and look up com.esri.android.map.MapView. Then scroll down the page and you find the available methods. It's the fourth method listed.  HTTPS://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/

Comment: Yep, you are correct on the ```MapView```, my bad, I was thinking of an issue we have when using the ```LocationDisplayManager``` which does not do this.  Off topic though, until we find out when @venom is trying to set the bounds.

Comment: It should work. In the JS API, I do the same thing when a buffer query is included in the url. I just let the map load, and within 1 second, the geometry data is returned, converted to a graphic, then the map is zoomed to that extent. Should work the same in Android, from what little I have dabbled in it.

Comment: In Android it is more specific than that, the calls should be made after ```GraphicsLayer```s are loaded, this is ensured with ```OnStatusChangedListener```.  Queries should be run on a background thread.